# What program constantly reads e-mails and could execute actions under certain conditions?

Tags: email, daemon

I need a program that would be running as a daemon, connecting to mail server and reading inbox of a specified e-mail address (provided with password, of course =) ). If certain conditions are met, it'd execute a script - and there could be many different conditions with many different scripts =) Conditions could include: sender address, e-mail topic&text, etc. Is there any program like I've described?

Comment: Can you run it on the mail server itself, or does it need to be remote? (If it is running on the server itself, there's about a billion, procmail coming to mind first.)

Comment: It needs to be remote - my idea is to use it as a remote control interface capable of breaking NAT =)

Comment: Sounds like a job for fetchmail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [`fetchmail`](http://fetchmail.sourceforge.net/) in conjunction with [`procmail`](http://pm-doc.sourceforge.net/doc/). Between the two of them, you should be able to solve all your automated mail-reading needs.

Comment: I guess mail retrieval isn't the most important part, software has to process them and act accordingly - that's the main feature for me.

Comment: @АрсенийПичугин: That's what procmail does. The useful part of fetchmail is that you can set it up to run as a daemon and pass the mail to procmail for processing.